# Subscribe all instances of class to notification center

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have a class with several instances running simultaneously. Can I subscribe some how all class to one notification ? So, for example, when one instance posts notification all other instances receive notification about it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Define a notification name and add observer for every instance.
1.Define notification name.

```
let allNotif = "allNotif"
```

2.Add observer.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "your_selector", name: allNotif, object: nil)
```